# Nested If Expression with user validation - repeating the prompt for user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, if-statement, for-loop

Thank you @Idor I am making some progress but I am not 100% there yet. Right now my code looks as following:

```
def easy_game(easy_text, parts_of_speech1):    
replaced = []
easy_text = easy_text.split()
i = 0
for word in easy_text:
    replacement = word_in_pos_easy(word, parts_of_speech1)
    if replacement != None:
        user_input = raw_input("Type in: " + replacement + " ")
        word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
        while word != solutions[i]:    
            print "Sorry, you are wrong"
            user_input = raw_input("Type in: " + replacement + " ")
            print i
        i = i + 1
        print i
        replaced.append(word)
    else:
        replaced.append(word)
replaced = " ".join(replaced)
print
#time.sleep(1)
print "Ok, lets see your results. Does it make sense?"
print
#time.sleep(1)
return replaced
print  
#time.sleep(1)
```

print easy_game(easy_text, parts_of_speech1)

You can see I added the `while` loop. I also added an index and for troubleshooting I added `print i` to see what the program is doing. It still confuses me a bit or doesn't work as I would expect it. But being a newbie to programming my expectations are probably wrong. Here's what's happening:

- When you enter the correct answer the program continues to question 2 and also increases i by 1
- This works from beginning to end if you enter everything correctly
- When you enter the wrong answer you are prompted to enter it again. Good!
- However the user then gets stuck in this very question although i has been increased to the right value.

I don't really understand why the user would be stuck at this point when i has been increased, i.e. we would check at the right position in the list for the correct answer.

This is the full code of the game. I can successfully run it on my Mac but see the above behavior. Any thoughts on this by any chance? thanks in advance!

```
parts_of_speech1  = ["Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4"]
        # The following is the text for the easy text..
easy_text = "Python is a Word1 language that provides constructs intended to enable clear programs on both small and large scale. Python implementation was started in December Word2 by Guido von Rossum. The most simple Word3 in Python is Word4 and normally used at the beginning to tell Python to write 'Hello World' on the screen."
solutions = ["programming", "1989", "function", "print"]
        # Checks if a word in parts_of_speech is a substring of the word passed in.
def word_in_pos_easy(word, parts_of_speech1):
            for pos in parts_of_speech1:
                if pos in word:
                    return pos
            return None 
        # Plays a full game of mad_libs. A player is prompted to replace words in the easy text, 
        # which appear in parts_of_speech with their own words.

def easy_game(easy_text, parts_of_speech1):

    replaced = []
    easy_text = easy_text.split()
    i = 0
    for word in easy_text:
        replacement = word_in_pos_easy(word, parts_of_speech1)
        if replacement != None:
            user_input = raw_input("Type in: " + replacement + " ")
            word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
            while word != solutions[i]:

                print "Sorry, you are wrong"
                user_input = raw_input("Type in: " + replacement + " ")
                print i
            i = i + 1
            print i
            replaced.append(word)
        else:
            replaced.append(word)
    replaced = " ".join(replaced)
    print
    #time.sleep(1)
    print "Ok, lets see your results. Does it make sense?"
    print
    #time.sleep(1)
    return replaced
    print

    #time.sleep(1) 
print easy_game(easy_text, parts_of_speech1)
```

I am building out a quiz based on raw_input using several different list operations. I also want to validate the user input against a list before moving on to the next question in the quiz.

The function currently looks like this:

```
def play_game(ml_string, parts_of_speech):    
replaced = []
ml_string = ml_string.split()
for word in ml_string:
    replacement = word_in_pos(word, parts_of_speech)
    if replacement != None:
        user_input = raw_input("Type in a: " + replacement + " ")
        word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
        if word != solution_list1[0]:
            print "Sorry, you are wrong. Try again!"
        replaced.append(word)
    else:
        replaced.append(word)
replaced = " ".join(replaced)
return replaced
```

In Line 9 I am checking against the List containing the solution words. Whereas the validation itself works the function just continues to the next question but I need it to repeat the question until getting the correct answer. I tried to reposition the different lines but simply can't get my head around it at this point in time. Where or how do I need to place the validation of the user input correctly to prompt the user for the same question again?

Comment: Christoph if you have an additional question please open another question. I would appreciate if you accepted my answer since it did solve this specific question. I can further help you with your new question when you open one.

Comment: I second Idos. Please do not "replace" your original question with information obtained from existing answers, then ask additional questions. This causes existing answers to become invalidated and unnecessary traffic to your question. If an answer solved your initial question, accept it. If you have new questions, make new posts and kindly ask the person who answered to help you again elsewhere

Comment: will do. Apologies for the inconvenience. I marked the question as answered and will open a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are looking for is a [`while`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop) loop.

Instead of:

```
if word != solution_list1[0]:
    print "Sorry, you are wrong. Try again!"
```

Try:

```
while word != solution_list1[0]:
    print "Sorry, you are wrong. Try again!"
    user_input = raw_input("Type in a: " + replacement + " ") # ask the user again
    word = word.replace(replacement, user_input)
```

This way the user will have to answer the question again (`raw_input`) until he gets it right.

Comment: Thank you @Idos I have edited my previous question by adding my progress so far. Apologies if you received quite a few notifications in regards to comments I posted. My machine was acting up a bit and might have posted, deleted multiple times.